# Promise and Done not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a simple `.append` loop iterating 100 times. At the end, I want to signal its completion, and it's not triggering.  Could anyone please explain why `.promise().done()` is not working here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var iterate = function(){
        alert("Start!");
        for(var i=1; i<101; i++) {
            $('body').append('Iteration ' + i + '<br>');
        };
    };

    iterate().promise().done(function(){
        $('body').append('Done! <br>');
        alert("Finished!");
    });
});
```

This isn't a special library. Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cdnatjsfiddle/85GJc/9/).  Thanks!

Comment: Appending is a synchronous operation. There is no point in doing this.

Comment: here, I fixed your fiddle, we already _have_ a `.done` (or more precisely a `.then` in synchronous code, it's called a semicolon http://jsfiddle.net/53GbK/

Comment: There is zero point to using a promise with an operation that is always purely synchronous.  It's just wasted, extra code that makes things look more complicated than they actually are.  Just put a semicolon after `iterate();` and then on the next line execute your next statement (as Benjamin showed you in the jsFiddle).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`iterate` that you define - doesn't return anything, so calling `promise()` on `undefined` results in error

you need to return `$('body');`

```
 var iterate = function(){
        alert("Start!");
        for(var i=1; i<101; i++) {
            $('body').append('Iteration ' + i + '<br>');
        };
       return $('body'); // add this line
    };
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the fact that the use of `promise` in this instance is actually completely useless since all of the `append` calls have already finished when `promise` is called.

Comment: This also worked for me.  (And also, couldn't stop the alert "Finished" from showing before the page appeared.  But it explained why nothing got appended at all.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`promise` is used to perform an action once all of the actions bound to the object *on which you're calling `promise`* are complete. This means that you don't want to call it on the result of the `iterate` call; you want to call it on `$('body')`:

```
iterate();
$('body').promise().done(function(){
    $('body').append('Done! <br>');
    alert("Finished!");
});
```

You'd see more benefit of doing this if you were performing an asynchronous operation; something that will actually continue to complete as your code continues, such as an animation.

As it stands, you might as well just do:

```
iterate();
$('body').append('Done! <br>');
alert("Finished!");
```

This has the same effect because, in the first example, all of the actions bound to `body` have already run. Nothing we did in `iterate` was asynchronous, so we didn't call `promise` until all of the `append` calls had *already finished*.

Comment: '$('body').promise().done(function(){..}' partly works, just that the alert pops up before the screen is seen at all.  Someone had me use .promise().done() on an XML parse .get(), and I hadn't understood why I couldn't just transfer that to here.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you still fully understand what's going on here, given that you've accepted an answer that is functionally identical to my first code snippet and, as I've said, doing that is pointless in this case because `iterate` is synchronous so you might as well just call your `append` and `alert` explicitly immediately after calling `iterate`.

Comment: You're right.  It had looked to me like the append was waiting for all the iterates, just because it appeared last.  Today I changed the iterations to 10000, then moved the append stuff in and out from under the .promise().done(), and it didn't make a squat of difference.  So, I decided to try this with an animation as you suggested, that I knew would take 5 seconds.  I modified the fiddle.  The code is waiting for the animation to finish, before "done" is appended.  Thanks for sticking with me. (I'm new to Stack and fiddle, and see that patience pays off as more people look at things.)